# Understanding assertion error message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm using unittest for some testing in Python. I have a simple test:

```
self.assertEqual(stdout, expected_stdout)
```

that really just checks the equality of two strings. 
When I run it I get an `AssertionError`, which is fine, but I'm not sure what the +/- below it mean. Example:

```
FAIL: unittest.case.FunctionTestCase (basic_test4)
actually pretty irrelevant
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/h/u16/c4/00/chenjoh6/csc209_advance_prep_ta/209-materials/assignments/a2/file-archive/20179/testing/a2_fs.py", line 33, in inner_meth_
    simple_test(["asd"], tc.dict_of_tests[name][1], tc.dict_of_tests[name][2] ,tc.dict_of_tests[name][0])(tfs)
  File "/h/u16/c4/00/chenjoh6/csc209_advance_prep_ta/209-materials/autotesting/20179/test_helpers.py", line 111, in _t
    self.assertEqual(stderr, expected_stderr)
AssertionError: 'or is it here(null)This is problemjohn\njohn: Success\n' != 'or is it here(null)john: Success\n'
+ or is it here(null)john: Success
- or is it here(null)This is problemjohn
- john: Success
```

(The first part to the left of the != is the actual output, the second part to the right of the != is the expected).

Can anyone help me understand how to read the +/-? Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual says "*if first and second are the exact same type [..] the type-specific equality function will be called in order to generate a more useful default error message*", and [that is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) it says "*a diff of the two strings highlighting the differences will be included in the error message*", so it's telling you which lines to remove and which to add to match the strings - in this case all of them except the blank last `\n`

Answer (score 1):

It is a line difference comparison of the two strings to change the left hand side to the right hand side.  `+` means you have to add the line `or is it here(null)john: Success` and `-` means to remove the lines `or is it here(null) this is problemjohn` and `john: Success`.

Since the left side only contains the two lines removed, and the right side only contains the one line added, that should make sense.  In this case a difference isn't very useful, but if the lines had more in common the difference would help narrow down the reason for the failure.